# How to check if a DOM node is fully visible to the user

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to determine if an object (or a piece of it) is really visible to user? I mean not within viewport (that's easy) but really visible (like not fully covered by any other object f.e. div or other, bigger image/element with opacity=1)

If anyone has any idea - please, share with me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+element+visible+covered+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please search your title before asking

Comment: You will need a screenshot-based comparison tool to verify a pre-verified output and a live one. there is no other way beside comparing pixels